# Ways to achieve an exact frame rate with the Linux framebuffer

Tags: linux, frame-rate, framebuffer

I try to write a program that draws a pattern like a chessboard and then changes the colors black <-> white with an exact frame rate. The frame rate should be adjustable beforehand. For each color change a trigger has to be output additionally. The trigger is a simply high edge on a GPIO pin.

Unfortunately I have no approach at all. Is it even possible to achieve an exact frame rate and output a trigger with each frame?

Comment: Welcom to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use double-buffering, make one buffer with your chessboard-pattern and the other buffer inverted. Then you can switch between the two buffers with the frame rate you want. Immediately before or after each switch you can change a gpio output.